# What is the expected cache behaviour when both Date and Expires values are in the past?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control, rfc2616

A fairly standard method for specifying cache behaviour in response headers is to set both a `Date` value and an `Expires` value. (Along with some kind of cache-control directive such as `cache-control=public`).

Assuming that a request is made at time *now*, let's say, *now* is:

`Tue, 24 Jun 2014 13:36:05 GMT`

Then a standard response which sets a cache value of 1 hour might include the following headers:

`Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 13:36:05 GMT`
`Expires: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 14:36:05 GMT`

This would (and should) tell any intermediary caches or PoPs to cache the resource for 1 hour from *now*.

However, what if both the `Expires` value **and** the `Date` value are in the past. (Perhaps, say, because of an erroneous server clock).

If we consider another request being made at the same time, with *now* being:

`Tue, 24 Jun 2014 13:36:05 GMT`

What if the corresponding response contained the following header values:

`Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 11:10:00 GMT`
`Expires: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 11:44:00 GMT`

Here, both values are already past. An `Expires` value in the past would normally be enough to trigger a `no-cache`, but what is the effect of the `Date` value being in the past.

Should cache implementations use the value of `Date` to calculate an offset from `Expires`, and then use that to create an expiry value of *now + offset*?

**RFC2616 Date section**
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18
Does not mention a Date value in the past

**RFC2616 Expires section**
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21
Stipulates that if `Date === Expires`, a reponse is *'already expired'*.

Neither of these seem to mention the case where both `Date` and `Expires` have already past?

**UPDATE / RFC2616 is Dead**
Further reading suggests that [RFC2616 is dead](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead) and has been superseded by a set of more specific RFCs.

The new [RFC7234 - HTTP/1.1: Caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) contains a [Calculating Freshness Lifetime](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.1) which contains the following statement:

> If the Expires response header field is present, use its value minus
> the value of the Date response header field

This seems to specify exactly what is outlined above - use an expires value of:

`expiry=(Expires - Date) + Now`

There does not seem to be any equivalent statement in the original RFC. For those still following RFC2616, is the behaviour up to individual browser/cache vendors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2616, the corresponding section is 13.2.3 Age Calculations.